# Json в nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

У меня строанное чувство появилось, что я немного не понимаю, что такое file.json в nodejs. В языках, с которыми мне приходилось сталкиваться, file.json был бы всего лишь внешним файлом, хранящим строку. Но в nodejs, когда я его подключаю, он уже является объектом?

```
var file = require('./file.json');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON — формат данных. По сути — строка, да. В большинстве ЯП есть средства для кодирования/декодирования такого формата. Node.js умеет автоматически преобразовывать JSON файлы в объект при импорте. Тем не менее если вы получаете такую строку из другого источника, ее можно декодировать при помощи глобального объекта `JSON.parse()` (и кодировать объект при помощи `JSON.stringify()`).